# route.MapPageRoute to a page with an extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, url-routing

In the global.asax of my website project (not MVC, not Web Application) MapPageRoute won't let me map to a page with an extension.

For example:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("GetMobilePassForAttendee", "Pass/Attendee/{attendeeId}", "~/GetMobilePass.aspx");
```

works as expected, but

```
routes.MapPageRoute("GetMobilePassForAttendee", "Pass/Attendee/{attendeeId}/pass.pkpass", "~/GetMobilePass.aspx");
```

returns a 404.

Anyone know why?

Perhaps I should be using URL rewriting, but all the material I've read has suggested I use  routing instead.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm having the same issue. This works: /FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml/ but this doesn't: /FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml because of the extension without the ending slash.

Comment: I actually didn't. I ended up not needing it. How did you go? If you have a solution, post it up and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested the "pass.pkpass" page separately, let say attendeeid=1 to see if Pass/Attendee/1/pass.pkpass is a working page without the routing?

Because .NET routing would not work in this case if this is a working page. It will skip the routing and load the actual "Pass/Attendee/1/pass.pkpass" page.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I can confirm that pass.pkpass does not exist. I'm actually getting a 404 regardless of what I put in, provided the period is there (i.e. an extension). So, if I put in Pass/this_file_doesnt_exist.html, I still get the 404. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("FederationMetadataRoute", "FederationMetadata/2007-06/{file}", "~/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.aspx")
```

And then I just check the `{file}` parameter to make sure it equaled `FederationMetadata.xml`

So in your case, just set `Pass/Attendee/{attendeeId}/pass.pkpass` to `Pass/Attendee/{attendeeId}/{pkpass}`

and check `{pkpass}` to make sure it equals `pass.pkpass` on your page.